# How to reference a javascript hash using a integer value when the key is a string?

Tags: javascript

My javascript hash on my web page looks like:

```
{"7":{"prop1":234, ....}"101":{"prop1":121,....}
```

I'm trying to reference it like this:

```
var a = 7;

my_hash[a].prop1
```

But it doesn't seem to find the hash object at the key 'a', since a is an integer and my keys are strings.

How can convert it to a string?

I tried:

```
my_hash[" + a + "].prop1
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: It should work just fine. If you supply a number, it is converted to a string by the property resolution algorithm. However, if your key is '07' it won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a string:

```
var a = "7";
```

If you have a number already, and want to make it a string, coerce it to a string this way:

```
var n = 7;
var a = n + "";
```

So, these all will work:

```
my_hash["7"].prop1;

var a = "7";
my_hash[a].prop1;

var n = 7;
var a = n + "";
my_hash[a].prop1;
```

**Edit:** Some examples converting it to a string inline:

```
my_hash[7 + ""].prop1;

var n = 7;
my_hash[n + ""].prop1;
```

Comment: how can I convert it to a string inline?

Comment: @Blankman - Where `n` is a number, just do `(n + "")`, parens optional depending on context.  I added a couple more examples.

Comment: How to check if the key exists, just do if(my_hash[a + ""])  or?

Comment: @Blankman - Use the [`in` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k25hbz2(VS.94).aspx): `if ((a + "") in my_hash)`.

Comment: But there is no need to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this:

```
var a = "7";

my_hash[a].prop1
```

or

```
my_hash["7"].prop1
```

Also, I'm assuming this was just a copy/paste into SO issue, but there's a missing comma in this:

```
{"7":{"prop1":234, ....}"101":{"prop1":121,....}
```

should be:

```
{"7":{"prop1":234, ....}, "101":{"prop1":121,....}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = {"7":{"prop1":234},"101":{"prop1":121}};
var a = 7;
console.log(x[a+""].prop1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ZGWHU/

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce the number into a string like gilly3 suggests. But you can also just call .toString on the number itself.  For example:

```
(1).toString() === "1" // evaluates to true.
```

This also works for variables so you could do this:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    property = myObject[i.toString()]["property"];
    // do something with property
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. You need two dots: `1..toString` as one dot will be interpreted as part of the number.

Comment: Ah, good point. But I think I'd rather do "(1).toString()". Edited.

Comment: Benry—yes, that is much preferred.